# Redirecting only root without changing the URL in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I'm redirecting only the requests coming to the root to a subfolder in the same server.
Now I would like to make the URL not change during the redirection.
My .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^$ /myFolder [R,L]
```

I tried to add P as an option, but it did not help. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
AliasMatch ^/$ /path/to/myFolder/
```

**Old reply:**

If you want to keep the query string, you must add the `QSA` option to your rewrite rule.

Comment: It's not about the query string, I just want the URL to show mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com/myFolder

Comment: See my new answer.